# What should I do if the built-in file, sprite.py, gets an error?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm new to python coding (I am 11 years old) and am practicing on a website that helps new coders make their first games, but I stumbled upon an error in sprite.py. The reason that I'm not sure how to handle this is that sprite.py was built in to the python files I downloaded. The error message says that add_internal() is missing a required positional argument: 'sprite'. I'm not quite sure how to fix this, as  I did not create or code sprite.py, nor did I make any edits to the file. Here is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aveil\Desktop\CodaKid Python 2\PEW PEW ROBO MASSACRE\src\main.py", line 46, in <module>
    PowerUp(screen, 300, 700)
  File "C:\Users\aveil\Desktop\CodaKid Python 2\PEW PEW ROBO MASSACRE\src\powerup.py", line 7, in __init__
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.containers)
  File "C:\Users\aveil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.add(groups)
  File "C:\Users\aveil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
  File "C:\Users\aveil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 139, in add
    group.add_internal(self)
TypeError: add_internal() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sprite'.
```

I'm not sure how to handle this error, but checked sprite.py to see if there were any problems that I could fix. I found no errors that I knew how to fix.

Here is the code from the Traceback error. I also include comments explaining the code for context. Apologies for the lengthy code snippet.

```py
##    pygame - Python Game Library
##    Copyright (C) 2000-2003, 2007  Pete Shinners
##              (C) 2004 Joe Wreschnig
##    This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
##    modify it under the terms of the GNU Library General Public
##    License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
##    version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
##
##    This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
##    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
##    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
##    Library General Public License for more details.
##
##    You should have received a copy of the GNU Library General Public
##    License along with this library; if not, write to the Free
##    Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
##
##    Pete Shinners
##    pete@shinners.org

"""pygame module with basic game object classes

This module contains several simple classes to be used within games. There
are the main Sprite class and several Group classes that contain Sprites.
The use of these classes is entirely optional when using Pygame. The classes
are fairly lightweight and only provide a starting place for the code
that is common to most games.

The Sprite class is intended to be used as a base class for the different
types of objects in the game. There is also a base Group class that simply
stores sprites. A game could create new types of Group classes that operate
on specially customized Sprite instances they contain.

The basic Sprite class can draw the Sprites it contains to a Surface. The
Group.draw() method requires that each Sprite have a Surface.image attribute
and a Surface.rect. The Group.clear() method requires these same attributes
and can be used to erase all the Sprites with background. There are also
more advanced Groups: pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates() and
pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates().

Lastly, this module contains several collision functions. These help find
sprites inside multiple groups that have intersecting bounding rectangles.
To find the collisions, the Sprites are required to have a Surface.rect
attribute assigned.

The groups are designed for high efficiency in removing and adding Sprites
to them. They also allow cheap testing to see if a Sprite already exists in
a Group. A given Sprite can exist in any number of groups. A game could use
some groups to control object rendering, and a completely separate set of
groups to control interaction or player movement. Instead of adding type
attributes or bools to a derived Sprite class, consider keeping the
Sprites inside organized Groups. This will allow for easier lookup later
in the game.

Sprites and Groups manage their relationships with the add() and remove()
methods. These methods can accept a single or multiple group arguments for
membership.  The default initializers for these classes also take a
single group or list of groups as argments for initial membership. It is safe
to repeatedly add and remove the same Sprite from a Group.

While it is possible to design sprite and group classes that don't derive
from the Sprite and AbstractGroup classes below, it is strongly recommended
that you extend those when you create a new Sprite or Group class.

Sprites are not thread safe, so lock them yourself if using threads.

"""

##todo
## a group that holds only the 'n' most recent elements.
## sort of like the GroupSingle class, but holding more
## than one sprite
##
## drawing groups that can 'automatically' store the area
## underneath so they can "clear" without needing a background
## function. obviously a little slower than normal, but nice
## to use in many situations. (also remember it must "clear"
## in the reverse order that it draws :])
##
## the drawing groups should also be able to take a background
## function, instead of just a background surface. the function
## would take a surface and a rectangle on that surface to erase.
##
## perhaps more types of collision functions? the current two
## should handle just about every need, but perhaps more optimized
## specific ones that aren't quite so general but fit into common
## specialized cases.

import pygame
from pygame import Rect
from pygame.time import get_ticks
from operator import truth

# Python 3 does not have the callable function, but an equivalent can be made
# with the hasattr function.
if 'callable' not in dir(__builtins__):
    callable = lambda obj: hasattr(obj, '__call__')

# Don't depend on pygame.mask if it's not there...
try:
    from pygame.mask import from_surface
except:
    pass


class Sprite(object):
    """simple base class for visible game objects

    pygame.sprite.Sprite(*groups): return Sprite

    The base class for visible game objects. Derived classes will want to
    override the Sprite.update() method and assign Sprite.image and Sprite.rect
    attributes.  The initializer can accept any number of Group instances that
    the Sprite will become a member of.

    When subclassing the Sprite class, be sure to call the base initializer
    before adding the Sprite to Groups.

    """

    def __init__(self, *groups):
        self.__g = {} # The groups the sprite is in
        if groups:
            self.add(*groups)

    def add(self, *groups):
        """add the sprite to groups

        Sprite.add(*groups): return None

        Any number of Group instances can be passed as arguments. The
        Sprite will be added to the Groups it is not already a member of.

        """
        has = self.__g.__contains__
        for group in groups:
            if hasattr(group, '_spritegroup'):
                if not has(group):
                    group.add_internal(self)
                    self.add_internal(group)
            else:
                self.add(*group)

    def remove(self, *groups):
        """remove the sprite from groups

        Sprite.remove(*groups): return None

        Any number of Group instances can be passed as arguments. The Sprite
        will be removed from the Groups it is currently a member of.

        """
        has = self.__g.__contains__
        for group in groups:
            if hasattr(group, '_spritegroup'):
                if has(group):
                    group.remove_internal(self)
                    self.remove_internal(group)
            else:
                self.remove(*group)

    def add_internal(self, group):
        self.__g[group] = 0

    def remove_internal(self, group):
        del self.__g[group]

    def update(self, *args):
        """method to control sprite behavior

        Sprite.update(*args):

        The default implementation of this method does nothing; it's just a
        convenient "hook" that you can override. This method is called by
        Group.update() with whatever arguments you give it.

        There is no need to use this method if not using the convenience
        method by the same name in the Group class.

        """
        pass

    def kill(self):
        """remove the Sprite from all Groups

        Sprite.kill(): return None

        The Sprite is removed from all the Groups that contain it. This won't
        change anything about the state of the Sprite. It is possible to
        continue to use the Sprite after this method has been called, including
        adding it to Groups.

        """
        for c in self.__g:
            c.remove_internal(self)
        self.__g.clear()

    def groups(self):
        """list of Groups that contain this Sprite

        Sprite.groups(): return group_list

        Returns a list of all the Groups that contain this Sprite.

        """
        return list(self.__g)

    def alive(self):
        """does the sprite belong to any groups

        Sprite.alive(): return bool

        Returns True when the Sprite belongs to one or more Groups.
        """
        return truth(self.__g)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s sprite(in %d groups)>" % (self.__class__.__name__, len(self.__g))
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

This is the PowerUp  **init**() statement for @Kingsly, thanks for your help!

```py
import pygame
import random
import toolbox

class PowerUp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.containers)
        self.screen = self.screen
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pick_power = random.randint(0, 0)
        if self.pick_power == 0: #Crate ammo
            self.image = pygame.image.oad("../update/powerupCrate.png")
            self.background_image = pygame.image.load("../assets/powerupBackgroundBlue.png")
            self.power_type = 'crateammo'
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
        self.background_angle =  0
        self.spinny_speed = 2

    def update(self):
        self.background_angle += self.spinny_speed
        bg_image_to_draw, bg_rect = toolbox,getRotatedImage(self.background_image, self.rect, self.background_angle)


        self.screen.blit(bg_image_to_draw, bg_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: Please format your question (traceback as code) and add the error related code!

Comment: Thank you @KlausD., I just edited my message and added what I hope is enough code to contextualize the problem.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly not in a library module, it's in how you are using the module.  The relevant code appears to be at the top of `powerup.py`, where you are creating this sprite.

Comment: Please include the code for the class `PowerUp()`, at least the `__init__()` function, this is where the problem is.  And "Pew Pew Robot Massacre" is an awesome name for a game BTW.

Comment: Alright, @Kingsley! I'll edit my question. (Thank you for noticing my superior taste in video game names!)

Comment: Thanks again @Kingsley! The edited information is above.

Comment: It looks like the issue is the extra argument in your call to sprite initialisation function, remove `self.containers` and `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)` should work. There are a couple of typos as well, e.g. `self.image = pygame.image.oad("` should probably be `image.load`. `self.screen = self.screen` should probably be `self.screen = screen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is probably the base-object `__init__` call in your PowerUp initialiser function.  Generally the class `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__()` function is only every passed `pygame.sprite.Group`, representing group-objects that this new sprite should be a member of.

So probably somewhere in your code, there is something like:

```
power_up_group     = pygame.sprite.group                 # <-- BUG!
PowerUp.containers = power_up_group
```

Which, theoretically causes new `PowerUp` sprites to be automatically added to the `power_up_group` sprite-group.

However, you've left the `()` off the end of the statement, it should be:

```
power_up_group = pygame.sprite.group()                   # <-- FIXED
```

The error your seeing is because, without the `()`, it's not creating a new group-object, just passing the definition of how to create a group.

Setting a class member like this is not a very good programming practice, as it makes the code less-readable and more complex for no real gain.  Any group can just be passed as a parameter to the sprite `__init__()`, *then* passed to the base-initialiser.  This makes it much clearer to see what's going on in the initialiser, because we don't have to hunt-around the code to work out what `self.containers` could possibly be set to.

```
class PowerUp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, x, y, power_up_group):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, power_up_group)     
        self.screen = self.screen
        # [...]
```

However if you're not using any of the sprite-group container logic, it can also just be removed from your class code:

```
class PowerUp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)      # <-- HERE, no containers
        self.screen = self.screen
        # [...]
```

And you can just add the sprites to a sprite-group after they are created.  Generally this is how I do it, since it's nice an obvious what's going on.

Comment: Alright, @Kingsley! I'll try your advise, thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone that commented! I really appreciate that you took time from your day to help me fix my error. Everything is working properly and running smoothly!

Comment: @Simone Glad I could help!